# Where do you go to find illustrations of car parts?

Tags: engine, automotive-design

I am trying to learn more about car engines but for the life if me can't find good illustrations of how some of them look (specifically a 2013 Nissan Juke) where do you go to get information and illustrations to get an accurate view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point you could do a search, say on Google, for something like "2013 nissan juke engine" – then in the results click on Images (at the top of the window under the address bar). That should get you headed in the right general direction.

You could get more specific by adding specific components that you'd like to see or by including a process that you're interested in. For example, **crankshaft** or **replace timing belt.**

Comment: I have done that but its not real giving me the correct results. In trying to find the engine block by its self.

Comment: You mean just the bare casting? As if you were going to start building an engine? That may be harder to find, they are kind of boring… Try searching on **short block** (with the crank and pistons but no accessories). Also, you may have better luck looking for line drawings or black & white in the advanced search. Also, you might find something if you look for blog posts on building a Juke engine. Asking on Juke forums might find you someone who has more specific  ideas.

Comment: Thanks bud. I found  drawing outlining it. Your awesome.

Comment: @LostPecti Also don't forget about the service manual. You can find copies on the internet sometimes, sometimes auto parts shops will have paper copies in stock. Also YouTube is an *excellent* resource for generic overview and concept videos.